# Как объединить символы в одну строку?

Tags: c, массивы

Есть char массив состоящий из 20 элементов, в каждый из них при чтении строки из файла заносится один символ из считанной строки. Как можно объединить обратно символы в строку, допустим, чтобы после этого использовать функцию поиска лексемы в полученной строке.

вот как считывается строка

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
char s[256];
FILE *in;
in = fopen("myfile.txt","rt");
if(in != NULL)
{
while(fgets(in,256,s) != NULL) 
{
/*
здесь производится обработка считанной строки
*/
}
fclose(in);
}
}
```

после записи символов в элементы массива, хотелось бы их объединить обратно, чтобы можно было в строке найти лексему

Comment: Не очень понятно. В Си строка и есть массив чаров, заканчивающийся '\0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

заведите массив на один элемент больше и в последний элемент запишите 0. (не '0', а '0'). Все, теперь этот массив можно передавать практически всем функциям, которые работают со строками.
А ещё правильнее, в самом начале массив весь занулить, а потом спокойно писать туда символы.

Comment: то есть, приравнять его значение к нулю?

Comment: char array[21];

.......

array[20] = '\\0';

Comment: @KoVadim, можно и не нулить в начале весь массив, главное в конце его поставить ноль.

Comment: я рекомендую строку всю обнулять, что то типа 

    int a[20];
    memset(a,0,20);
Почему? да все предельно просто. Завтра запишете на один символ меньше в строку и будете ломать голову и форумы вопросом - а что это за символ такой в конце моей строки, а почему strlen выдает не ту длину строки, которую я ожидаю (а он просто ищет конечный ноль и не более).

Comment: Можно без memset'а:

    char a[20]={0};

 Кстати, почему у тебя int? Опечатка? Если нет, то строка с memset обнулит только четверть массива.

Comment: упс, там куда то пропал sizeof(int). Да, конечно, нужно зануливать правильное **кол-во байт**.

Comment: Только строка - это char[], а не int[], как у тебя. Тогда sizeof int не нужен.

Comment: @GLmonster, у меня в конструкции

char a[20]={'a'};

только первый чар получает соответственное значение.

Comment: Зато остальные символы все нулевые. Если не использовать инициализацию, то все символы будут неопределеными. Этот трюк работает только с обнулением.

Comment: Это точно? Откуда такая информация, можете дать источники?